# help for tedious counting problem

Tags: exponentiation, maxima-minima, integers

for an integer $\mathscr k$ ($2\leq k\lt500$) four positive integer a,b,c,d satisfies following conditions

1. $2\leq a,b,c,d\leq k$
2. $a^{\frac{1}{b}}\times c^{\frac{1}{d}}=24^{\frac{1}{5}}$

for k which makes $\vert{\{(a,b,c,d)\}}\vert=59$,
find maximum and minimum value of k.

($\vert{\{(a,b,c,d)\}}\vert$ denotes the number of (a,b,c,d)

---

I tried brute force approach and obtained

k= 6: (4 5 6 5) (6 5 4 5) 2pairs

k= 8: (3 5 8 5) (8 5 3 5) 2pairs

k= 10: (9 10 8 5) (8 5 9 10) 2pairs

k= 12: (2 5 12 5) (12 5 2 5) (4 10 12 5) (12 5 4 10) 4pairs

k= 15: (8 15 12 5) (12 5 8 15) 2pairs

k= 16: (16 10 6 5) (6 5 16 10) 2pairs

k= 18: (18 10 2 2) (2 2 18 10) (18 10 4 4) (4 4 18 10) (18 10 8 6) (8 6 18 10) (18 10 16 8) (16 8 18 10) 8pairs

k= 20: (16 20 12 5) (12 5 16 20) 2pairs

k= 24: (24 10 24 10) 1pair

k= 27: (27 15 8 5) (8 5 27 15) 2pairs

k= 30: (24 6 24 30) (24 30 24 6) 2pairs

k= 32: (32 25 12 5) (12 5 32 25) (18 10 32 10) (32 10 18 10) 4pairs

k= 36: (4 5 36 10) (36 10 4 5) (16 10 36 10) (36 10 16 10) 4pairs

k= 48: (18 35 48 7) (48 7 18 35) (12 10 48 10) (48 10 12 10) 4pairs

k= 64: (27 15 64 10) (64 10 27 15) (9 10 64 10) (64 10 9 10) (18 10 64 15) (64 15 18 10) (3 5 64 10) (64 10 3 5) (6 5 64 15) (64 15 6 5) (64 15 36 10) (36 10 64 15) (64 30 12 5) (12 5 64 30) 14pairs

k= 72: (8 10 72 10) (72 10 8 10) (64 20 72 10) (72 10 64 20) 4pairs

summing all gives 59 pairs. and if k=81, there exists (81 20 8 5) (8 5 81 20) (81 20 64 10) (64 10 81 20) so $72\leq k\leq80$

But the answer was 359 (maxima+minima) and I don't understand why. This is a question in an important exam in my country. Please help me.

Comment: Are you sure the problem is stated correctly? Maybe the first should read $$2 \leq a < b < c < d \leq k$$ or something like that?

Comment: When $(a,b,c,d)$ is a solution, so is $(c,d,a,b)$. If $(a,b) \ne (c,d)$, then solutions come in pairs. But you need an odd number of solutions. Therefore you need at least one solution (more generally, an odd number of solutions) of the form $(a,b,a,b)$ - i.e., integer solutions of the equation $a^{10} = 24^b$. Start by solving that - it will give you an idea on what values $k$ can have.

Comment: You might check to see if they are not counting $(a,b,c,d)$ and $(c,d,a,b)$ as separate solutions. That might be why your brute force calculation has come up with an answer lower than theirs. This can depend on exactly how the question is phrased, and you have evidently not given us an accurate translation of the question, since nothing in what you said would justify giving the sum of the maximum and minimum as the answer.